# ValueError when attempting to concatenate Pandas dataframes by reading CSV into multip chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, valueerror

I have loaded csv file into pandas dataframe with 5 chunk because chunk is useful while displaying large dataset at once. It prints 5 rows in each iteration. Here is my code of dividing dataframe into chunk and displaying the result.

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
path = 'data/diabetes.csv'

df_reader = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=5)

for index, chunk in enumerate(df_reader):
    if index < 5:
        print(f'Chunk index: {index}')
        display(chunk)
```

Below is the output of first two iteration above.
[image: First two iteration of total chunksize*2 data]
Now from middle, when i need data in single chunk, there is a problem. I tried to store existing data in new dataframe `df` by concanating into single chunk, but it raise `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`. Below is my code.

```
# Create an empty list to store the individual DataFrames
df_list = []

for chunk in df_reader:    
    # Append each chunk to the list if not empty
    df_list.append(chunk)

# Concatenate all the DataFrames 
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

You can see I have created a new dataframe called df_reader at the beginning, by reading a CSV file in 5 chunks. However, I am currently facing an issue while trying to concatenate these chunks into a single dataframe called df. Whenever I attempt to do so, I receive the error message: ValueError: No objects to concatenate.

Can you help me identify the cause of this error and suggest a solution?

Comment: Once you have consumed your iterator, it is empty. You can't iterate on it anymore.

Comment: well, Thank you for providing a concept behind it.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:

```
df_reader = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=5)
pd.concat(df_reader)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I see after iterating, all chunks is consumed and the iterator becomes empty, so that I was unable to iterate over it anymore.